# count id, insert, then update by number range in another columns in same table mysql

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I am trying to update levels in db like this:
"count (id) from users table where referral_id = id As aggref set agg_referral = aggref AND level = 1 if aggref in between 1 to 3"
So far i know but no success :(

**Here is my db structure
users table:**

```
  id (AI)      name       Referral id      agg_referral   Level
=========== ========== ================== ============== ======
     1        user A          0                 0          0
     2        user B          3                 0          0
     3        user C          1                 0          0
     4        user D          3                 0          0
```

**Here is my code i am running it using cron job:**

```
  <?php
    include( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/config.php' );
    mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS);
    mysql_select_db(DB_NAME);
    $query="UPDATE users SET agg_referral = (SELECT COUNT(id) from users WHERE users.referral_id = users.id)";
    mysql_query($query);

    ?>
```

> I am expecting results like this

```
 id (AI)      name       Referral id      agg_referral   Level
=========== ========== ================== ============== ======
     1        user A          0                 0          0
     2        user B          3                 0          0
     3        user C          1                 2          1
     4        user D          3                 0          0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an update join:

```
update users u1
join (
    select referral_id,
        count(*) cnt
    from users
    group by referral_id
    ) u2 on u1.id = u2.referral_id    
set u1.agg_referral = u2.cnt,
    u1.level = case 
        when cnt < 1
            then 0
        else ceil((- 5 + sqrt(25 + 8 * cnt)) / 2)
        end;
```

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/EVQMR47717)

It finds times an id is referred and then join it with the table to update the counts and level.

The case statement produces 0 for cnt = 0 or less, 1 for cnt between 1 and 3, 2 for cnt between 4 and 7 and . . so on.

To learn more on how the formula works, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2171745/find-group-number-for-a-given-number-from-groups-of-increasing-size

#### EDIT:

If your initial group size is value other than 3, use this to get the required equation:

```
ceil((1 - 2 * g + sqrt(4 * g * g + 1 - 4 * g + 8 * cnt)) / 2)
```

where g is the intial size of the group.

For g = 3, it solves to:

```
ceil( -5 + sqrt(25 + 8 * cnt) / 2 )
```

for g = 10, it solves to:

```
ceil( -19 + sqrt(361 + 8 * cnt) / 2 )
```

On how this function is made, see the link provided above.

Comment: this is working, but there's one problem i don't want level go down to 0, right now when (cnt between 4 and 7), level going back to 0 but i want level = 2 when (cnt between 4 and 7) and keep increasing like this, however  only in case agg_referral < 1 than i want to output level = 0

Comment: what if we do it in 2 steps `step1- update agg_referral` `update level based on agg_referral values i.e: agg_referral in between 1 to 3 set level = 1 And agg_referral in between 4 to 7 set level = 2` or if you have smart solution that will be awesome

Comment: @Jamez Shouldn't it be 4 to 6 instead? assuming window of 3

Comment: @JamezRoz - Updated the answer. Please check

Comment: it shouldn't be `4 to 6 ` because, agg_referral count will keep increasing, think your id in my db is = 3 and today 1,2 or 3 people signup using your referral code, so in this case your level will remain 1 once 4,5 or 6 users signup using your code, you level should be in this case = 2 and keep increasing like this

Comment: i have tested new answer edit, it's not updating agg_referral & level

Comment: @JamezRoz - Updated the answer. It contains a formula to calculate the level based the group you defined.

Comment: i appreciate it, you did it very well, it's helped me alot, keep the good work up ...

Comment: there's some problem how can i set diffrent group size, for 3 you have added 2 in formula, what in group size = 10 or 15?

Comment: @Grv -something wrong in new edit, formula not working, look's like i cannot change the group size because of advance math, i am not very good in math ? or do you have any other solution

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, you can do this by counting the number of referrals for each id using a subquery.  Then use that information in the `update`:

```
UPDATE users u JOIN
       (SELECT referral_id, COUNT(*) as cnt
        FROM users u
        GROUP BY referral_id
       ) ur
       ON u.id = ur.referral_id
    SET u.agg_referral = ur.cnt,
        u.level = (CASE WHEN ur.cnt BETWEEN 1 and 3 THEN 2 ELSE level END);
```

Comment: This is exactly what i need cheers !, can you do a little improvement after testing come in my mind, how can we have multiple cases in single query i.e: `(CASE WHEN ur.cnt BETWEEN 1 and 3 THEN 1  AND CASE WHEN ur.cnt BETWEEN 4 and 5 THEN 2 ELSE level END)` any solution for multiple cases ?

Comment: @JamezRoz . . . The `CASE` expression readily generalizes to handling multiple conditions.

Comment: please edit your answer with multiple `(CASE WHEN ur.cnt BETWEEN 1 and 3 THEN 1 AND CASE WHEN ur.cnt BETWEEN 4 and 5 THEN 2 ELSE level END)` i don't know how to do this ?